# How to stream a .ts without any re-encoding

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, avconv

I'm trying to just stream a ts file to test some software on my network. I've been running this command:

```
avconv -re -i originalfile.ts -f mpegts udp://127.0.0.1:10000
```

But I noticed that its re-encoding the "originalfile.ts" and spitting out an transport stream that is an encoded version of originalfile.ts. When I do a socat the quality of the output from above looks degraded vs playing the originalfile.ts straight off from vlc.

I just want to stream the original file in all its entirety without any encoding of any sort. But I cant seem to find the command for that. Everything looks like its muxing or converting of some sort.

Thanks

Comment: Do options `-vcodec copy -acodec copy` work?

Comment: not really looks like it still tried to downgrade the quality. Not sure whats going on..